# Drive was unable to assemble into the array

Tags: linux, software-raid, mdadm, raid

I ran

```
mdadm -A /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

Only `/dev/sdb1` was loaded into the array though. I have a few more arrays on the same two drives too. Each time the partition on `sda` failed. `dmesg` told me that `sda` was out of sync... Since this was from a rescue cd. I've disconnected `sda` (hardware wise) for the time being, since it was preventing me from booting.

How should I proceed? Is this likely the cause of a borked drive? I had some weird fs issues the other day I couldn't track down (maybe a precursor): missing files that later magically re-appeared. Maybe a missing cable?

The main question is how do I try to re-sync the drive?

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid10] 
md3 : active raid10 sda4[1]
      955683840 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 far-copies [2/1] [_U]

md2 : active raid10 sda3[1]
      10483712 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 far-copies [2/1] [_U]

md1 : active raid10 sda2[1]
      10484736 blocks 512K chunks 2 far-copies [2/1] [_U]

md0 : active raid10 sda1[1]
      101376 blocks 512K chunks 2 far-copies [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>
```

*update*

I ran `badblocks` on the whole other drive, and a long `smartctl` test, it found no problems.

a request output of `mdadm -D /dev/md0` *(I have md0-3 if others are needed)*

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Mon May 31 20:24:14 2010
     Raid Level : raid10
     Array Size : 101376 (99.02 MiB 103.81 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 101376 (99.02 MiB 103.81 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Oct 25 07:58:25 2010
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : far=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

           UUID : 30ffe1d2:f5759995:820bb796:b5530bd2 (local to host slave-iv)
         Events : 0.212

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8        1        1      active sync   /dev/sda1
```

Since I've found no actual issues with the drive, but obviously something went wrong, I'm wondering what I should do next? *as of today a full backup of important data is in place*

*update 2* Whenever I try to add what was `sda` back in (at least without wiping it) it screw's up my boot process with a kernel magic number error. I'm guessing because the kernel version got out of sync. currently this drive is in an external enclosure as `sdd`. Should I re-add (re-sync) this drive while it's connected via usb? will that 'cause problems?

```
df
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   10M  284K  9.8M   3% /dev
/dev/md1              9.9G  7.0G  2.4G  75% /
shm                   3.0G  1.5M  3.0G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/md0               96M   15M   77M  16% /boot
/dev/md2              9.9G  6.5G  3.0G  69% /var
/dev/md3              898G  451G  402G  53% /home
none                  1.0G   45M  980M   5% /tmp
/dev/sdb1             992M   36M  956M   4% /media/D4A4-B7C1
```

each md drive has an sda/sdb corresponding. it was the sda drive (or 0 drive) in the array that I had to pull.

Comment: In don't understand why you've disconnected `/dev/sda`, yet `sda` appears in `/proc/mdstat`; and how do you do raid10 with only two disks? What does `mdadm -D /dev/md0` show? Do you have any log message about drive trouble? Does smartctl report any problem? Have you run a RAM test recently? You could `mdadm --add` the desynchronized disks, but if you have an underlying hardware problem, it's not a good idea.

Comment: when I disconnected `sda`, `sdb` became `sda` via the kernel.

Comment: I ran smarctl like a few days before and didn't see any problems... (haven't run since because I was in a livecd only env)

Comment: [wikipedia can explain raid10,f2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#Linux_MD_RAID_10)

Comment: raid10 would imply to me at least 4 devices; you seem to be effectively operating in raid1 mode.

Comment: Regarding *update 2*: could you provide details such as (1) what disks are in your system, (2) what device your / and /boot reside on, (c) what bootloader you are using?

Comment: @ephemient raid10,f2 is a special mdadm thing, see the wikipedia article for an explanation of how it can work on 2 disks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, clearly one of your disks is not active in the array right now.  Let's say, under the current enumeration, that `/dev/md0` is missing `/dev/sdb1`.

To add `/dev/sdb1` back in its former state:

```
mdadm -a --re-add /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1
```

You may want to re-check the array to make sure the data is all consistent.

```
echo check >>/sys/block/md0/md/sync_action
```

To re-mirror from scratch:

Make sure that `/dev/sdb1` is completely removed from the array.

```
mdadm -f /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1
mdadm -r /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1
```

Wipe out the configuration on `/dev/sdb1` so that `mdadm` will add it to back to the array as if it were a completely new disk.

```
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb1
```

Add `/dev/sdb1` back to the array as a member.

```
mdadm -a /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1
```

---

Syncing a disk on USB works, slowly.

However, I would guess that your problem is that your bootloader isn't installed properly on your second drive, which is preventing you from booting when it's inserted.

You could swap the order of those two drives, so that your system boots off of the drive with known good configuration.

Once you are up and running and can sync both drives, you should re-install the bootloader on both drives.  This way you can always boot no matter which drive is missing or enumerates first.

How to re-install your bootloader varies:

- If you are using `lilo` ≥ 22.0, specify `boot = /dev/md0` and `raid-extra-boot = mbr` in `/etc/lilo.conf` and re-run `lilo`.  If you are using an older `lilo`, create two lilo configurations, one for each disk in the the array, and install `lilo` to each disk individually.
- If you are using Grub, try to run `grub-install /dev/sda` and `grub-install /dev/sdb`.  If that fails, then try using the Grub shell to `setup (hd0)` and `setup (hd1)` (`cat /boot/grub/device.map` to see what Grub's hard disk numberings are).

Comment: part of the problem is that `/boot`, and everything else* was out of sync once I re-synced all the partitions it just worked. I tried `grub-install` first and it just left grub more broken. Maybe should consider removing that, idk.